# code ship fails with error - You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command

Tags: codeship

For my angular CLI/Bitbucket project I am running following script in Codeship but it gives error `You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command.`

```
#install node version, 4.x is required for the angular-cli
nvm install 4.1

#install angular-cli
npm install angular-cli 

#run npm install for your project dependencies
npm install
```

Under that script is the "Test Pipelines", where the script is setup to run the tests.

```
#serve the application adding '&' to run command in background
ng serve &

#start end to end tests using protractor
ng test

#if all of the tests pass, then build the production assets
ng build -prod
```

Comment: Ahoy :) Judging from the error message it seems like the `ng` CLI doesn't recognize the project as an Angular project. Out of curiosity, did you already create a ticket on https://helpdesk.codeship.com and if not, could you create one and include a link to the failing builds? We'd be happy to take a look and help you solve this.

Comment: I have raised this ticket. I am told to run SSH debug but I am finding it difficult to follow the steps. Even after I have added the ssh key, the console asks for `password` which I suppose it shouldn't - Ticket is https://helpdesk.codeship.com/hc/en-us/requests/15489

Comment: Alright, let me take a look at that ticket and get back to you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4379 this error message is usually triggered if you're using the (now deprecated) `angular-cli` package.

Either update the `package.json` file for the project to reference the `@angular/cli` package, or make sure to install this package instead of the deprecated one.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with Shippable, especially without any log files. Did you try my suggestion on Codeship and see if it worked (or failed with a different error message that is caused by a different error)?

Comment: My apologies, I got confused. I shouldn't have mixed them up. I'll try to delete my comment and try your suggestion.

Comment: didn't work :(. New configuration is `#install node version, 4.x is required for the angular-cli
nvm install 6
#install angular-cli
#npm install angular-cli
#run npm install for your project dependencies
npm install`

Comment: some progress. Instead of commenting angular/cli, I added `npm install @angular/cli@latest`. I do not get `ng serve` error but am stuck in production now. Will work on it. However, I don't understand why @angular/cli didn't get installed from `package.json`

Comment: production error is `ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/ManuChadha/angularcli/src'
@ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
@ multi ./src/main.ts`

Comment: I am accepting your answer as the main issue is resolved. thank you.